# Configurable product price is zero in the front-end

Tags: magento2, price, import

I am probably missing somtheing obvious. When I import configurable products the price in the front-end is zero. Beneath is a examples of one product and the columns that I believe is necessary to get my point across.

- Note that there also are a size attribute that is not show here.
- Magento will set price field to zero if empty on import.
- All prices are including tax

**UPDATE:**
"configurable_variations" and "additional_variations" fields are setup correctly as well.

**Example 1:**

Product list: 0,00 DKK

Product page: 0,00 DKK (When choosing the a size the price stays zero.)

```
sku store_view_code attribute_set_code  product_type    product_websites    name            description short_description   weight  product_online  tax_class_name  visibility                  price   special_price
2999000222568       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222568                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    0       0
2999000222575       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222575                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    0       0
2999000222582       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222582                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    0       0
2999000222599       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222599                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    0       0
2999000222605       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222605                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    0       0
2499FIRE RED        Configurable        configurable    danmark             jacket                                                  1               Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search             1200    840
```

**Example 2:**

Product list: 1050,00 DKK <strike>1.200 DKK</strike>

Product page: 0,00 DKK (When choosing a size the price changes to -325. The tax is 25%)

```
sku store_view_code attribute_set_code  product_type    product_websites    name            description short_description   weight  product_online  tax_class_name  visibility                  price   special_price
2999000222568       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222568                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    1200    840
2999000222575       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222575                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    1200    840
2999000222582       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222582                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    1200    840
2999000222599       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222599                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    1200    840
2999000222605       Configurable        simple          danmark             2999000222605                                   0       1               Taxable Goods   Not Visible Individually    1200    840
2499FIRE RED        Configurable        configurable    danmark             jacket                                                  1               Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search             1200    840
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding any Configurable product using CSV you need to add **configurable_variations** in your CSV so your Configurable product can have their associative products.

so your CSV should be like this :

```
sku                price        visibility              type         configurable_variations
2999000222605      1200     Not Visible Individually    simple 
2999KT             1200     Catalog, Search            configurable  sku=2999000222605
```

Comment: saperate sku with  "|"

Comment: Sorry, didn't include that in the question, it is now.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Nope, it seems that Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax have some influence too. But Product list stil show as 0,00 DKK

Answer (score 0):

We are using 3rd party product importer and found $0 for configurable but showing the correct price for option selection. After saving one of the child products manually in admin, configurable started showing the correct price of $42.95 in the frontend.