# Magento 2 - Configurable product price in frontend 0.00 - backend is ok

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product

We have set up a shop with Magento 2.1.7, all products were imported via the Rest API and everything in the backend looks good. Prices are shown on parent and child products. But in the frontend the price from the configurable products is 0,00€ (grid and detail view), if we choose a variant like color and size the product price switches to the correct price.
Does anyone have a idea where to look?

Reindex was already made.

Configurable Product
[image]

Variant choosen
[image]

Update:
It seems that Magento will take a special price for rendering, but there is no special price for the product. See HTML

```
<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"
 itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span class="price-label">Sonderangebot</span>
    <span  id="product-price-6822"                data-price-amount="0"
    data-price-type="finalPrice"
    class="price-wrapper "
     itemprop="price" content="0">
    <span class="price">0,00 €</span>    </span>
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
</span>
</span>
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">


<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
<span class="price-label">Normalpreis</span>
<span  id="old-price-6822" data-price-amount="319.99" data-price type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
    <span class="price">319,99 €</span>    </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Tried to reindex the catalog_product?

Comment: 1. The config price 0.00 is default product price is 0.00 
2. If you like to get the default value, then you need to update view.phtml and list.phtml
3. Instead of config price should apply associated product price (super attribute)  in the price.phtml

Please Provide me the source code I can help you

Comment: Thx
Niko K Yes, reindex was made.
rajiv in the backend the config price is correct.

Comment: We fixed it. The problem was, that the special price in the table 'catalog_product_entity_decimal' for the products was 0 instead of NULL. Changing it fixed the wrong display.

Comment: This worked for me in Magento 2.3.5-P1 - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/321352/3906

Answer (score 2):

We fixed it. The problem was, that the special price in the table 'catalog_product_entity_decimal' for the products was 0 instead of NULL. Changing it fixed the wrong display.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've all the valid data, still it is showing $0.

I've fixed this below way.. Not sure is this correct/valid fix.

Followed the below link, and over ridden a file, this fixed $0 price for configurable products.. but still "As low as" label displaying

[how magento getting configurable product lowest price of associated products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135513/how-magento-getting-configurable-product-lowest-price-of-associated-products)

Then I've updated final_price.phtml as per my requirement (removed "As low as" related code) from module-configurable-product module.

In Magento 1.x price related code executed from one phtml file, where as in M2 price from two files (different files for Simple and Configurable products).. I'm not sure is this a special feature of Magento 2.x

Hope this will helps some one...